# Simple async example with tornado python

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I want find simple async server example. 
I have got some function with lot of wait, database transactions ... etc:

```
def blocking_task(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        print i
        sleep(1)
    return i
```

I need run it function in separated process without blocking. Is it possible?

Answer (score 18):

Tornado is designed to run all your operations in a single thread, but utilize asynchronous I/O to avoid blocking as much as possible. If the DB you're using has asychronous Python bindings (ideally ones geared for Tornado specifically, like [Motor](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) for MongoDB or [momoko](https://github.com/FSX/momoko) for Postgres), then you'll be able to run your DB queries without blocking the server; no separate processes or threads needed.

To address the exact example you gave, where `time.sleep(1)` is called, you could use this approach to do it asynchronously via tornado coroutines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tornado.web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen 
import time

@gen.coroutine
def async_sleep(seconds):
    yield gen.Task(IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + seconds)

class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            print i
            yield async_sleep(1)
        self.write(str(i))
        self.finish()


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/test", TestHandler),
    ])  

application.listen(9999)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The interesting part is `async_sleep`. That method is creating an asynchronous Task, which is calling the `ioloop.add_timeout` method. `add_timeout` will run a specified callback after a given number of seconds, without blocking the ioloop while waiting for the timeout to expire. It expects two arguments:

```
add_timeout(deadline, callback) # deadline is the number of seconds to wait, callback is the method to call after deadline.
```

As you can see in the example above, we're only actually providing one parameter to `add_timeout` explicitly in the code, which means we end up this this:

```
add_timeout(time.time() + seconds, ???)
```

We're not providing the expected callback parameter. In fact, when `gen.Task` executes `add_timeout`, it appends a `callback` keyword argument to the end of the explicitly provided parameters. So this:

```
yield gen.Task(loop.add_timeout, time.time() + seconds)
```

Results in this being executed inside gen.Task():

```
loop.add_timeout(time.time() + seconds, callback=gen.Callback(some_unique_key))
```

When `gen.Callback` is executed after the timeout, it signals that the `gen.Task` is complete, and the program execution will continue on to the next line. This flow is kind of difficult to fully understand, at least at first (it certainly was for me when I first read about it). It'll probably be helpful to read over the [Tornado gen module documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html) a few times.

Comment: why not use async await for gen_async function?

Comment: @amrx This answer was written before async/await was added to Python.

Answer (score 7):

```
import tornado.web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen

from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor   # `pip install futures` for python2

MAX_WORKERS = 16

class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS)

    """
    In below function goes your time consuming task
    """

    @run_on_executor
    def background_task(self):
        sm = 0
        for i in range(10 ** 8):
            sm = sm + 1

        return sm

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        """ Request that asynchronously calls background task. """
        res = yield self.background_task()
        self.write(str(res))

class TestHandler2(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write('Response from server')
        self.finish()


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/A", TestHandler),
    (r"/B", TestHandler2),
    ])

application.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When you run above code, you can run a computationally expensive operation at http://127.0.0.1:5000/A , which does not block execution, see by visiting  http://127.0.0.1:5000/B immediately after you visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/A.

Comment: how `executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS)` is connected to the execution ?

Answer (score 3):

Here I update the information about Tornado 5.0. Tornado 5.0 add a new method [`IOLoop.run_in_executor`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor). In the "Calling blocking functions" of [Coroutine patterns](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html) Chapter:

> The simplest way to call a blocking function from a coroutine is to use IOLoop.run_in_executor, which returns Futures that are compatible with coroutines:
>
> `@gen.coroutine
>   def call_blocking():
>       yield IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(blocking_func, args)`

Also, in the documeng of [`run_on_executor`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html?highlight=%20%40run_on_executor), is says:

> This decorator should not be confused with the similarly-named **IOLoop.run_in_executor**. In general, using run_in_executor when calling a blocking method is recommended instead of using this decorator when defining a method. If compatibility with older versions of Tornado is required, consider defining an executor and using executor.submit() at the call site.

In 5.0 version, IOLoop.run_in_executor is recommanded in use case of Calling blocking functions.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.5 introduced the `async` and `await` keywords (functions using these keywords are also called “native coroutines”). For compatibility with older versions of Python, you can use “decorated” or “yield-based” coroutines using the `tornado.gen.coroutine` decorator.

Native coroutines are the recommended form whenever possible. Only use decorated coroutines when compatibility with older versions of Python is required. Examples in the Tornado documentation will generally use the native form.

Translation between the two forms is generally straightforward:

```py
# Decorated:                    # Native:

# Normal function declaration
# with decorator                # "async def" keywords
@gen.coroutine
def a():                        async def a():
    # "yield" all async funcs       # "await" all async funcs
    b = yield c()                   b = await c()
    # "return" and "yield"
    # cannot be mixed in
    # Python 2, so raise a
    # special exception.            # Return normally
    raise gen.Return(b)             return b
```

Other differences between the two forms of coroutine are outlined below.

- Native coroutines:

  - are generally faster.
  - can use `async for` and `async with` statements which make some patterns much simpler.
  - do not run at all unless you `await` or `yield` them. Decorated coroutines can start running “in the background” as soon as they are called. Note that for both kinds of coroutines it is important to use `await` or `yield` so that any exceptions have somewhere to go.
- Decorated coroutines:

  - have additional integration with the `concurrent.futures` package, allowing the result of `executor.submit` to be yielded directly. For native coroutines, use `IOLoop.run_in_executor` instead.
  - support some shorthand for waiting on multiple objects by yielding a list or dict. Use `tornado.gen.multi` to do this in native coroutines.
  - can support integration with other packages including Twisted via a registry of conversion functions. To access this functionality in native coroutines, use `tornado.gen.convert_yielded`.
  - always return a `Future` object. Native coroutines return an awaitable object that is not a `Future`. In Tornado the two are mostly interchangeable.

---

Worth to see:

- [Simplest async/await example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64508472/13155046)