# Call a method without expecting a response

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a server-side application to listen for connections and call a method based on what the client says. However when I call the method upload i want to continue executing code under main.

Is there anyway i can achieve this, or am i taking the incorrect approach? Code below;

```
def main(ipAddr, tcpPort, bufferSize, s):
    try:
        s.bind((ipAddr, tcpPort))
        s.listen(4)
        conn, addr = s.accept()

    print("Connection attempt from: %s" % addr)
    messageRecv = ""
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(bufferSize)
        if not data: break
        messageRecv = data.decode('utf-8')
finally:
    conn.close()
    if messageRecv == "Ready": upload(addr)

main(ipAddr, tcpPort, bufferSize, s)



def upload(addr):
    pass
```

Comment: I would recommend to read about Multithreaded Programming. you can see this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: Fix the indentation, please.

Comment: If you are on a recent version of Python, you want to take a look at the [`asyncio` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).  For older versions of Python, use [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module, which is essentially Python's "multithreading" package. The API is very similar to the `threading` module's, but `threading` may be prohibitive due to the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock).

In your case, you may have something like this:

```
p = Process(target=upload, args=(addr,))
p.start()
# some other code
p.join()
```

Comment: I support this answer but I will however always recommend that you give a shot at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) a much lightweight solution to a multi-thread / multi process paradigm. And if you are interested into asyncIO in server side try also [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/0)

Comment: Python's threading module is very often useful, and networking is a prime example of an application of threading.  The GIL is a non-issue for many applications, since most applications aren't CPU-bound, but rather I/O-bound.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Fair enough; I guess that statement was somewhat harsh.

Comment: An useful SO thread with example of using Tornado - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920877/simple-async-example-with-tornado-python