# Mix tornado.gen.coroutine with async/await?

Tags: python, tornado

I need to change the following legacy tornado code to call an async function `async def my_async1(self)`.

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, action):
        ....
```

Can they be mixed? How to refactory the code?

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine 
    async def get(self, action):
        ....
        await self.my_async() # ?
```

Can I just remove `@gen.coroutine` and add `async`? Are they exactly the same?

Comment: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66090798/13155046)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, they are *almost* the same. `@gen.coroutine` is from old days when Python didn't have `async/await` keywords. So `@gen.coroutine` was used for turning regular functions (or generators) into asynchronous generators.

For newer python versions (3.5+), the `async/await` syntax should be preferred over `@gen.coroutine`.

Keep these things in mind while converting the functions:

1. Don't decorate `async def` functions with `@gen.coroutine` (like you've done in your second code example).
2. Replace `yield` keyword with `await` keyword.
3. `yield None` statement works but `await None` doesn't.
4. You can `yield` a list (such as `yield [f1(), f2()]`), but with `await`, use `await gen.multi(f1(), f2())` or `await asyncio.gather(f1(), f2())`. (Thanks to Ben for mentioning this.)

Comment: Curiously, the code has to import tornado before Python 3.5? Since `gen.coroutine` is in tornado. BTW, you said *almost the same*, what's the difference if they are not identical?

Comment: @ca9163d9 `@gen.coroutine` is for generators (with `yield` statements), whereas a `async def` functions are actual coroutines (with `await` statements). Otherwise, they work pretty much the same.

Comment: There are a few things that work a little differently. For example, in `@gen.coroutine` you can do `yield [f1(), f2()]` to do things in parallel. In `async def`, you have to use a wrapper object like `await gen.multi(f1(), f2())` or `await asyncio.gather(f1(), f2())`

Comment: Slight modification worked for me. Instead of await gen.multi(f1(), f2()), pass a list of the functions in. Looks like this: await gen.multi([f1(), f2()])